# Запрос к БД

Tags: база-данных, mysql

```
$a = 4558
```

Как вывести из бд значения, которые меньше $a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `name` WHERE `value` < $a");

while(...) {
 ...
}
```